# Estimate gas cost for transaction to custom Solana Program written with Anchor

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-program-library

How can I get a gasFee estimate for a transaction of my custom contract?

For a normal transaction execution from the SPL library I can do so like this:

```
import { Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';

const transaction = new Transaction({
  recentBlockhash: recentBlockhash.blockhash,
  feePayer: wallet.publicKey
}).add(
  // someFunctionCall
);
const estimatedGas = await transaction.getEstimatedFee(connection);
```

But I do not use `new Transaction()` to call my custom Program's methods. It's done like:

```
const tx = await program.methods
        .myCustomMethod(...)
        .accounts(...)
        .rpc();
```

How can I estimate the gas for the `tx` w/o actually calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out you can replace `.rpc()` with `.transaction()` which will return an object of type `Transaction` (from `@solana/web3.js`).

Then you can exercise the same logic for gas estimation on that object as in the first example.

And, of course, you will need to `sendAndConfirm` the transaction as an extra step,  because otherwise the `.rpc()` call was taking care of that.

Answer (score 1):

A demo example to print estimated gas cost for transaction created usign Anchor:

```
const txn = await program.methods
  .exchange10(sBump, BNF(exchangeBal1))
  .accounts({
    feeRecipient: feeRecipient.publicKey,
    seller: sellerPDA,
    sellerTokenAccount: sellerTknAcc.address,
    buyer: wallet2.publicKey,
    buyerTokenAccount: buyerTknAcc.address,
    tokensForSale: tokensForSalePDA,
    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  })
  .signers([wallet2])
  .transaction();

txn.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
txn.feePayer = wallet2.publicKey;
console.log(await txn.getEstimatedFee(connection))
```